# Paradox in Godel's statement

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

I am new in mathematical logic and trying to understand the Godel's incompleteness theorem. If i'm not mistaken, it claims that in arithmetic there exists a statement $G$ such that there don't exist proofs of $G$ and $\sim G$  (if arithmetic and logic rules are consistent)

If I understand correctly, the key of the proof is to construct the expression $G$ which says "it doesn't exist a proof of $G$".

Help me to resolve the following paradox:
From Godel's theorem follows that "it doesn't exist a proof of $G$". So it exists a proof that "it doesn't exist a proof of $G$", which is nothing but $G$. So it exists a proof of $G$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Gödel's theorem doesn't say "there is no proof of G." What it says is (as you yourself indicated in parentheses) "IF PA (Peano arithmetic) IS CONSISTENT, then there is no proof of G in PA." (That "IF" is actually an "IF AND ONLY IF" since, if PA is inconsistent, then everything including G is provable in PA.)

Now PA is more than strong enough to prove Gödel 's theorem. However, proving Gödel's theorem in PA does not prove that G is unprovable, it only proves that G is unprovable IF PA IS CONSISTENT.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now I don't understand why we can't a bit modify the Godel's statement to the following one: $G$ = "IF PA IS CONSISTENT then it doesn't exist a proof of $G$". Then it seems my paradox remains valid?

Comment: @David: avoid simply saying "doesn't exist a proof of G". You should always say what theory the proof is supposed to use, e.g. "doesn't exist a proof of G in PA".  If we don't talk about a particular formal system, there is no way to rigorously define the set of proofs that we are considering, and so there is no way to rigorously state the sentence you have quoted in your previous comment.

Comment: @CarlMummert, I still don't understand, what if I reformulate the $G$ in a way you proposed: $G$  = "IF PA IS CONSISTENT then it doesn't exist a proof of $G$ in PA". What would happened with my paradox?

Comment: @David - what we get is that we can prove G, but we can't prove G in PA, so there is no paradox. We need extra axioms to prove G, namely the axiom that PA is consistent, which is not provable in PA.

Comment: Let G = "if PA is consistent then G is unprovable". Then G is provable in PA if and only if "PA is inconsistent" is provable in PA. In reality, G is NOT provable in PA.